# I am facing error while scraping the data

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to find the data from a website.

```
url = "https://www.screener.in/company/ALMONDZ/"
```

I wanted to find Low value

```
i.e.= 8.87
```

which is in span class number.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.screener.in/company/ALMONDZ/")
text=driver.find_element_by_class_name("class").getText("text")
print(text)
```

I am not able to fetch the value. Kindly let me know what mistake is in the code to fetch the low value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find it by `XPATH`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.screener.in/company/ALMONDZ/")
text = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="top-ratios"]/li[3]/span[2]/span[2]').text
```

Output:

```
8.87
```